# Ill-posed covariance matrix

Tags: correlation, networks

I have a gene expression matrix $A$ with dimension $7000\times 30$ where $A_{ij}$ represents the  expression of gene i at time j. I need to make a gene co-expression network but the problem is the $7000\times 7000$ correlation matrix between genes computed from matrix A is ill-posed since n>>p. How to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) I think what Xeon means is to SHRINK towards a diagonal matrix. See for instance
http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/ShrinkCovMat/ShrinkCovMat.pdf

2) Another common approach is to assume that the covariance matrix is a multiple of the Identity matrix (not enough information to estimate the covariances even if they exist).

3) A third approach is to resort to a low rank reconstruction of the matrix (using the SVD) to retain only those components which explain a large percentage of the variance in the data

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is I don't want to shrink my covariance  towards a diagonal matrix since in that case all I get is isolated nodes. I just want to denoise the covariance matrix. Does putting a threshold on the covariance matrix denoise it?

Comment: What do you mean by isolated nodes? It can be shown that putting a threshold of some form essentially boils down to ridge/lasso type penalized formats

Comment: By isolated nodes, I mean 0 degree nodes (nodes with no connections) in the network.

Answer (score 1):

A cheap way to go away from ill-posed matrix is to add some small value to the diagonal. I am not sure though if you can do this in your particular method (please provide details for it).